# Sending data from C++ to Website

Tags: javascript, c++, html, amqp

I'm recently working on a project where I have classes written in C++ and a website which is written with HTML5 and JavaScript. Now I want to have data from the C++ program sent to the website. Which way is the best to solve that?

I was looking around for AMQP, WebSockets and JSON. But I didn't get how I can use them and what is the best for this problem and how I can use these technologies.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I recommend to use the C++ webtoolkit Wt (pronounced Witty), at [http://www.webtoolkit.eu/](http://www.webtoolkit.eu/wt).

This framework (with integrated application server) lets you design web applications in terms of widgets and signal/slot connections, and leaves much of the web cruft in the hands of the library. The resulting applications are object-oriented, strictly typed, and perfectly maintainable. The library autodetects the browser's capabilities and uses the proper way to render the site, avoiding browser bugs.

Wt is written in a modern C++ style, which doesn't need to lead to memory leaks and other mishaps that have always been associated with C++ applications. C++ is as good as any other language around. It is not a matter of performance, it is a matter of style.

Comment: I think that is not what I'm looking for exactly. I just have to transfer data from a C++ program to the website which has JavaScript. I don't need to program a whole new website. I just want to get a connection between these two parts and send data.

Comment: Thank you. That is something I can work with. How do I setup a connection? Do I have to install a server between these two JavaScript and C++?

Comment: You'll need a web server.

Comment: I'd suggest to go for Wt. You can use existing website with some modifications. http://www.webtoolkit.eu/wt/examples/hello/hello.wt

Comment: Thank you. But I don't know how to set up this thing. I have the HTML5 page and the C++ program. What do I do with Witty now?

Comment: Change your HTML files and make them as template for Wt. Something like this: http://www.webtoolkit.eu/widgets/layout/html-templates

Comment: It's just that I have a table in my HTML page and this table should be filled with data that comes from the C++ program. Also doable with Witty?

Comment: Yes, have a look at the documentation for a moment, everything is there.